# Switching Binding Sources using a MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a DataBinding with a MultiBinding of two ObservableCollections, and i want to switch between them on a condition with a MultiConverter. 
So the converter gives the right collection, but the binding doesn't seem to be updated.

Any Ideas??

Greets,

Jürgen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the converter you need:

```
public class SwitchCollectionsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool b = (bool)values[2];

        if (b)
            return values[0];
        else
            return values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

registering the converter:

```
    <local:SwitchCollectionsConverter x:Key="TheConverter" />
```

usage of the binding:

```
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TheConverter}">
                <Binding Path="FirstCollection" />
                <Binding Path="SecondCollection" />
                <Binding Path="IsFirst" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    </ItemsControl>
```

under the assumption that you have a FirstCollection, a SecondCollection, and an IsFirst Properties in the DataContext

Comment: Thats what i have, and it seems to be working, but my View doesn't seem to be updated if the original Binding was replaces with the other one from the MultiBinding. I always have the old data shown in the tree...

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on ALL THREE properties? (yeah, having ObservableCollections here won't help)

Comment: I think that has nothing to do with it. Lets say the original binding is on FirstCollection, and will change to SecondCollection, so the Binging will change, not the collections themself... or am i wrong here??

Comment: I'll be damned, it actually works.... Suoulda have tried it before replaying... ;). Nice Work!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the view to update the source lists?

If so, your binding should be in TwoWay mode:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source, Mode="TwoWay"}" />
```